# Internet Explorer does not support j query for selecting check box values

Tags: jquery, ajax

for getting selected check-box values i m using  a j query which is run fine under chrome , Firefox but fails in IE. For certain reasons i gave same id for each check-box but use different names. for example

```
     <input id="LIV" name="<?php echo $value['desc']; ?>" type="checkbox" checked value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" /> <?php echo $value['desc']; ?>

       <a class="i-btn-2" onclick="addparameters('LIV');">Add</a>
```

On click of add button i call a function addparameter which is as follows

```
               function addparameters(id)
              {

                 var tempstr='#'+id+':checked';

                  $(tempstr).each(function(i)
                  {
                        val[i] = $('#'+id).val();
                        val1[i]=($(this).attr('name'));
                        str12=str12+val[i];
                    });
                 }
```

In IE if i selected more than one check-boxes it gives me only first check-box value.But in chrome it gives me all selected check-boxes values
What is wrong with my code. Please help me to run it on IE

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, names don't need to be.

Comment: *"For certain reasons i gave same id for each check-box but use different names."* That's invalid markup. [`id` values **must** be unique on the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute) (that's an HTML5 link, but it's not a remotely new requirement).

Comment: This seems to work for me in IE9.  The `:checked` selector makes `#LIV:checked` return multiple elements, but `#LIV` only returns one.  This might have something to do with the way jQuery handles it's pseudo-selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Neal said - each checkbox must have different ID - even every element in Your HTML has to have different ID - ID is what it is supposed to be - an IDENTIFICATOR and the IDETIFICATOR uniquely describes one concrete item.

Instead of ID You can use class or the same input name:

```
function addparameters(name) {
    var selector = $('input[name="'+name+'"]:checked');
    $(selector).each(function(i){
        val[i] = $(this).val();
        val1[i] = name;
        str12 = str12+val[i];
    });
}
```

or

```
function addparameters(class) {
    var selector = $('input.'+class+':checked');
    $(selector).each(function(i){
        val[i] = $(this).val();
        val1[i] = $(this).attr('name');
        str12 = str12+val[i];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to give all the checkboxes **DIFFERENT** id's.

If they all have the same id, they will **not** select properly...

Right now **all** of your checkboxes have the `id="LIV"`, use something like a common class to select all of them instead.

Comment: You *can* cheat a bit by doing this: `$('[id="'+id+'"]')`, but I suggest you *don't*.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting an ID instead of a class. Only one element can have the same ID, but multiple elements can share classes. So change the id into a class and it will start working. e.g.

```
var tempstr='.'+yourClass+':checked';
```